# How might I customize the display of an auto-complete pop-up 'window'?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to get auto-complete pop-up windows *just right* within emacs, and I'm pretty close to something I like:

[image: Emacs pop-up]

but in a perfect world, I would be able to customize the border, margin, and padding of the help box generated. I've scoured the documentation, tried playing around with pos-tip, but just can't get this right.

Any suggestions on how I can get a bit more customization out of the display of my auto-complete pop-ups?

Comment: There are nothing built into popup.el to do what you describe, you can modify left and right margins but that is about it. Everything else will require source modification. (From what I can tell)